# "Simple" If-Statement not working within small piece of code [Beginner] [Java]

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm creating a method to let the user know how much money would have been saved if they decide to switch to another package.

```
public static String savingsCalc(char pack, double hours)
{
    String returnVal = "";
    double packageRateA = 9.95;
    double packageRateB = 13.95;
    double packageRateC = 19.95;
    double savings = 0;

    if (hours > 10) packageRateA = 9.95 + ((hours - 10) * 2.00);

    if (hours > 20) packageRateB = 13.95 + ((hours - 20) * 1.00);

    if (pack == 'A')
    {
        if (packageRateA < packageRateB) returnVal = "";

        else if (packageRateA < packageRateC && packageRateA > packageRateB)
        {
            savings = packageRateA - packageRateB;
            System.out.printf("You would save $%.2f if you switched to package B!%n", savings);
        }

        else if (packageRateA > packageRateC)
        {
            savings = packageRateA - packageRateC;
            System.out.printf("You would save $%.2f if you switched to package C!%n", savings);
        }

    }

    return returnVal;
}//shows savings if changing to other package
```

If I enter "15" hours, it should print savings for "Package B" but does not, I checked that all the values are correct by printing the line, but I don't understand why it won't print.

Comment: What are the parameters you are passing?

Comment: I am passing the number of hours and the package letter.

Comment: Yeah. I can see that. What are the values?

Comment: derp. The values are "A" for pack, and "15" for hours.

Comment: None of your `if` statements are `true`, so it's returning an empty String. Probably because `packageRateA == packageRateC`, so perhaps change it to `else if (packageRateA <= packageRateC && packageRateA > packageRateB) {` and it will output `You would save $6.00 if you switched to package B!`

Comment: aha! Thanks a bunch, that clears it up! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`packageRateA` becomes 19.95 because `hours > 10`. `packageRateB` stays at 13.95. `packageRateC` stays at 19.95.

Is this true?

```
packageRateA < packageRateB
```

No, A is greater.

Is this true?

```
packageRateA < packageRateC && packageRateA > packageRateB
```

No, A and C are the same.

Is this true?

```
packageRateA > packageRateC
```

No, A and C are the same.

So none of the conditions are true and `returnVal` remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are checking `packageRateA < packageRateC`. 
Which doesn't get satisfied when you pass the argument.

packageRateA would be 19.95 when `hours=15.00` which is equal to packageRateC.

If you change the condition to `packageRateA <= packageRateC` your code would work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logic.  If I assume the value passed in for pack is A, then the following line changes packageRateA to 19.95:

```
if (hours > 10) packageRateA = 9.95 + ((hours - 10) * 2.00);
```

After that line, packageRateA is the same value as packageRateC and more than packageRateB. 
None of the conditional statements evaluate to true with those values.

If you want it to select packageRateB, you need to change the logic in this conditional

```
else if (packageRateA < packageRateC && packageRateA > packageRateB)
```